# Relationship in XAMPP between two tables and inserting data into each in c#

Tags: c#

I have a question that I can't seem to figure out. I'm creating an application that adds a client's information then relate it to a service that is being provided. I created the relationship between the two tables in xampp database. The tables are tclientinfo and tserviceinfo. The columns in the tclientinfo table are Client_ID(PK), First_Name, Last_Name, Phone, and Email. In the tserviceinfo, Service_Order, Date, Tech, Brand, Model, OS, Type, PC_Issue, Service, Service_Price, Total_Price, Service_Notes, Client_ID. Client_ID is what I'm using as the relationship, but I am unable to add information to the tserviceinfo table. I'm getting the SQL exception: Cannont add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails('dbocomputerinformation'.'tserviceinfo',CONSTRAINT 'tserviceinfo_ibfk_3' FOREIGN KEY('Client_ID') REFERENCES 'tclientinfo' ('Client_ID') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE).

My add button to insert information into tclientinfo is:

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;password=Passwordwhatever;database=dbocomputerinformation;");
            conn.Open();

```
        string email = tbEmail.Text;
        string date = tbDate.Text;

        //try statement for validation before sending to database. 
        try
        {
            if (tbFirstName.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in customer's first name.");
                this.tbFirstName.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbLastName.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in customer's last name.");
                this.tbLastName.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbPhone.Text.Length < 10)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Phone number must be ten digits.");
                this.tbPhone.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbPhone.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in customer's phone number.");
                this.tbPhone.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbPhone.Text != string.Empty && !Regex.IsMatch(tbPhone.Text, @"^[0-9]+$"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in numbers only.");
                this.tbPhone.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbEmail.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in customer's email.");
                this.tbEmail.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (email.IndexOf('@') == -1 || email.IndexOf('.') == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address.");
                this.tbEmail.Focus();
                return;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into tclientinfo (First_Name, Last_Name, Phone, Email) values (?First_Name, ?Last_Name, ?Phone, ?Email)", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?First_Name", tbFirstName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Last_Name", tbLastName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Phone", tbPhone.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Email", tbEmail.Text);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Client Added Successfully.");

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't connect to database\n" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then my insert into tserviceinfo is:

private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //string connString = "server=localhost;uid=root;password=Passwordwhatever;database=dbocomputerinfo;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;password=Passwordwhatever;database=dbocomputerinfo;");
            conn.Open();

```
        string date = tbDate.Text;

        //try statement for validation before sending to database. 
        try
        {
            if (tbDate.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in date of service.");
                this.tbDate.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (date.IndexOf('-') == -2) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter correct date. mm-dd-yy.");
                this.tbDate.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbTech.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in service technician.");
                this.tbTech.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbBrand.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in customer's brand of computer.");
                this.tbBrand.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbModel.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in computer model.");
                this.tbModel.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbOS.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter in computer's operating system.");
                this.tbOS.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (rbDesktop.Checked == false && rbNotebook.Checked == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select device type.");
                this.rbDesktop.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (lvOrdered.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a service.");
                this.lvServices.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (tbIssue.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please describe the issue with the computer.");
                this.tbIssue.Focus();
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into tserviceinfo (Date, Tech, Brand, Model, OS, Type, PC_Issue, Service, Service_Price, Total_Price) values (?Date, ?Tech, ?Brand, ?Model, ?OS, ?Type, ?PC_Issue, ?Service, ?Service_Price, ?Total_Price)", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Date", tbDate.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Tech", tbTech.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Brand", tbBrand.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Model", tbModel.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?OS", tbOS.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?PC_Issue", tbIssue.Text);

            /**
             * Was having issues inserting a single service, it would dublicate itself in the db, this was the solution
             * this adds just a single service with nothing else, and it reads back properly as well. 
            **/
            if (lvOrdered.Items.Count == 1)
            {
                string singleService = string.Join(" ", services);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Service", singleService);
            }
            else
            {
                /**
                * Combine all the services into one string seperated by commas
                * and add that to the database
                * */
                string serviceList = string.Join(", ", services);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Service", serviceList);

            }
            /**
             * Combine all the prices into one string seperated by commas
             * and add that to the database
             * */
            string servicePriceList = string.Join(", ", servicePrice);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Service_Price", servicePriceList);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Total_Price", lblPrice.Text);

            //clears lists so dublicates don't happen when creating more work orders than just 1.
            services.Clear();
            servicePrice.Clear();

            if (rbDesktop.Checked)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Type", "Desktop");
            }
            else if (rbNotebook.Checked)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Type", "Notebook");
            }

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            tbFirstName.Clear();
            tbLastName.Clear();
            tbDate.Clear();
            tbEmail.Clear();
            tbBrand.Clear();
            tbIssue.Clear();
            tbTech.Clear();
            tbModel.Clear();
            tbPhone.Clear();
            tbOS.Clear();
            lvOrdered.Items.Clear();
            lblPrice.Text = "$0.00";

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't connect to database\n" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

So needless to say, I'm not positive on what to do from here. Any help would be awesome or any ideas. If you need anymore information, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys, sorry for being dumb. But I needed to select the Client_ID and store it as a variable. Then insert it into the second table.

So like this if anyone else has this question ever.

intMaxClientId;

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select max(Client_ID) from tclientinfo", conn);
                maxClientId = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Client_ID", maxClientId);